# Extracting all (possible) optional date values from web page [R]

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

In [this url string](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2013-2014&month=MAY&timelineView=date&toDate=1399849199999&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS), "**toDate=1399849199999**" part of the string refers to UNIX time expressed in milliseconds which is used to extract the Premier league table for a particular day.

In this case, UNIX time refers to 11. may of 2014.

```
as.POSIXlt (1399849199999/1000, tz = "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01")
```

I would like to retrieve all possible UNIX time values for a particular month. For url provided here, those 6 values are stored in webpage source code and it looks like this:

```
<select name="toDate" id="date" class="selectToSlider" widget="selectToSlider" labels="18" tooltip="false" wrapperClass="selectToSliderWrapper selectToSliderMatchDate"><optgroup label="results"><option value="1399157999999">SAT 03</option><option value="1399244399999">SUN 04</option><option value="1399330799999">MON 05</option><option value="1399417199999" selected="selected">TUE 06</option><option value="1399503599999">WED 07</option><option value="1399849199999">SUN 11</option></optgroup><optgroup label="fixtures"></optgroup></select>
```

Previously I used to extract such information with regular expressions but it was the pain in the *neck* (***) and I want to do this in some easier way.

I appreciate if someone can provide the code (possibly with explained steps) that can extract those values using some web scraping packages in R, preferably **XML**. I tried it by myself but I was unsuccessful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using XML package to parse the html from the link you provided, then extract the specific information required (out of the whole html) using xpath:

```
library(XML)
EPL.URL <- "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2013-2014&month=MAY&timelineView=date&toDate=1399849199999&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS"
EPL.doc <- htmlParse(EPL.URL)
xpathSApply(EPLdoc, "//optgroup[@label='results']/option", xmlGetAttr, "value")
```

Comment: please can you explain what "//optgroup[@label='results']/option" means?

Comment: XPATH is a method of extracting information from XML nodes. Here, we need to access all _option_ nodes that are the children of the _optgroup_ node with attribute _label="results"_. I figure that using `"//option"` path will give us more than needed.  
For more information, try these:  
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp; 
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`rvest` makes this pretty easy. Look for the "option" nodes, then grab the "value" attributes.

```
library("rvest")
h <- read_html('<select name="toDate" id="date" class="selectToSlider" widget="selectToSlider" labels="18" tooltip="false" wrapperClass="selectToSliderWrapper selectToSliderMatchDate"><optgroup label="results"><option value="1399157999999">SAT 03</option><option value="1399244399999">SUN 04</option><option value="1399330799999">MON 05</option><option value="1399417199999" selected="selected">TUE 06</option><option value="1399503599999">WED 07</option><option value="1399849199999">SUN 11</option></optgroup><optgroup label="fixtures"></optgroup></select>')
h %>% html_nodes("option") %>% html_attr("value")
[1] "1399157999999" "1399244399999" "1399330799999"
[4] "1399417199999" "1399503599999" "1399849199999"
```

Comment: How this works if h would be an url string instead of part of the webpage source code?